# How can I create and reference an external function for bind() in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Currently I have in my < head>:

```
$(function() { 
    $('input[type=\'submit\']').bind('click', function(event){ 
        /// Really long jQuery function with direct DOM element references
    });
});
```

The problem with the function is that it´s really long with multiple if, else and if else conditions and I figured it would be much cleaner to include it in an external file and reference it as the second parameter to the bind() method. How is that possible? How do I reference the function in the external file and how do I reference to it in the main file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, you just pass the function to `.bind`:

```
// file A, must be included before file B
function foo(event) {

}

// file B
$(function() {
    $(...).bind('click', foo);
});
```